# how can I make a function that prints out a menu?

Tags: c++

I'm playing around with functions and i wanted to know if it was possible to make a menu but have it in a function and then call the function in the main. An example would be:

```
cout << "Enter 1 for info" << endl; 
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << "Enter 2 to Start" << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << "Enter 3 to Quit" << endl;

    cin >> menu;
```

I want this but in a function with if and else statements so it would print out another statement depending on what the user chooses. Im using the c++ language.

thanks

Comment: Generally all questions on the form "is it possible to do X" can be answered by a simple "yes". Yes, it's possible to put the code you show inside a function different from `main`.

Comment: Try with a FSM?

Comment: Of course it is possible to do something like this. Everything is possible in C++.

Comment: Please open your C++ book and read about functions. Sloppy speaking, we usually dont teach you how to walk, but we happily help you when you fall

Comment: sorry guys I'm new to c++ how would i go about doing this?

Comment: do you know how to write and call a function? Note that there is no function in your example, so it isnt clear what help you actually need

Comment: Find a HelloWorld-based tutorial, follow it and the following tutorials. Sooner or later you will encounter one which gets close. Then modify it to get closer to your goal. When you have a problem then ask a question here.

Comment: You go about this the same way you go about writing anything else in C++: by opening your text editor, typing in some code, trying to compile it, and then seeing if it works. Can you show what you already wrote? You have to show your work first; it must meet all requirements for a [mre]; and it must be a good-faith real attempt to implement your program and not a few token lines of code, before asking for help on stackoverflow.com. We don't write entire programs for other people, here. For more information, see [ask] questions, take the [tour], and read the [help].

Comment: i read about it and can create and call a function but the one thing im struggling on is well getting a menu setup in a function with if and else statements attached

Comment: If you show the code which can do what you describe, just not inside a function, then we could help you refactor it.

Comment: if you're really just starting out, also consider following some courses, like [john purcell's one](https://caveofprogramming.teachable.com/p/c-beginners)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example to get you started:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int MenuSelect() {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter 1 for info" << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << "Enter 2 to Start" << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << "Enter 3 to Quit" << endl;

    int selected = 0;
    string input;
    cin >> input;
    if (stringstream(input) >> selected) {
        return selected;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}

void start() {

}

int main() {
    int selected = -1;
    while ((selected = MenuSelect()) != 3) {
        if (selected < 1) {
            cout << "Invalid option" << endl;
        }
        else if (selected == 1) {
            cout << "Info" << endl;
        }
        else if (selected == 2) {
            cout << "START!" << endl;
            start();
        }
        else {
            cout << "Invalid option" << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```